# SCP from server1 to server2 using server0 over ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to send a file from server1 to server2 by accessing server1 from server0 on SSH. I have added all servers' pub_keys in authorized_files of all 3 servers. I can connect to any server from any other server without manually entering any password. I want to ssh server1 from server0 and then SCP a file from server1 to server2. I think it should work like this.

```
user0@server0:~$ ssh user1@server1 "scp -r filename user2@server2:~/${location}"
```

But this is not working. There is no error response. Both src and dest are correct. But the file is not copied. 
Is there any mistake in above command? 
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: While connected to server1 via ssh from server0, issue another ssh session from server1 to server2 and send  the file.

Comment: I tried it earlier.  Same issue.

Comment: Try `sftp server2` then `cd` to destination directory then `put filename` . Make sure your username has write permission to destination directory.